# Alarm is not fired after memory is cleared

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, android-memory

I am writing some code to fire alarm at a specific time. Everything is working fine and alarm is fired as expected.

But when I clear memory using some **Memory Cleaner app**, then the alarm is not fired.

I have added permissions and intent-filter for **Boot Completion** that set my alarm after device boot. But I don't know how to reset my alarm if any Memory Cleaner app cleans the memory?

Code for setting alarm

```
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

Intent intent = new Intent(context, DailyAlarmService.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, Constants.DAILY_ALARM_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 5000, pIntent);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't think you have to reset the alarm, alarm service will be restarted even after memory cleaned, but some devices are very strict that they restrict autostart of an app, even some popular apps doesn't work properly on Xiomi redmi devices.

Comment: I set alarm, and it fires properly. But I set another alarm, and then clear memory. this time the alarm does not fire.